# GCD Program in Assembly doesn't show the output of gcd

Tags: loops, assembly, masm, irvine32, greatest-common-divisor

This builds successfully and there is nothing wrong with typing integers. However, I can't see the outcome of gcd and the debugger runs without anything. Is it because of the infinite loop? I am totally lost in here. Could anyone figure out what I am missing here? Please help me what is wrong with this?

```
    INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.data

strA BYTE "Enter an integer A: ",0
strB BYTE "Enter an integer B: ",0
temp DWORD ?
finalStr BYTE "GCD of the two integers is: ",0



.code

main PROC

call Clrscr

mainLoop:
mov edx,OFFSET strA
call WriteString
call ReadInt
mov temp, eax
call Crlf

mov edx, OFFSET strB
call WriteString
call ReadInt        
mov ebx, eax
mov eax, temp
call Crlf

call GCD

mov edx, OFFSET finalStr
call WriteString
call WriteInt

call WaitMsg

jmp mainLoop

main ENDP


abs PROC
   cmp eax, 0                    ; see if we have a negative number
   jge done
   neg eax

done:
   ret
abs ENDP


gcd PROC
call abs        ;takes absolute value of both registers
mov temp, eax
mov eax, ebx
call abs
mov  ebx, eax
mov eax, temp

cmp eax, ebx    ; making sure we divide the bigger number by the smaller
jz DONE     ; if numbers are equal, GCD is eax either way
jc SWITCH   ;swaps if ebx is larger then eax

mov edx, 0

SWITCH:         ;swaps values so eax is larger then ebx
mov temp, eax
mov eax, ebx
mov ebx, temp
mov edx, 0
jmp L1

L1:     ;divides until remainder is 0, then eax is GCD
div ebx
cmp edx, 0
jz DONE
mov eax, edx
jmp L1


DONE:
gcd ENDP

END main
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll tell you one thing wrong with that code straight up (there may be *other* issues, that's just the one that immediately popped out):

```
jc SWITCH   ;swaps if ebx is larger then eax

mov edx, 0

SWITCH:         ;swaps values so eax is larger then ebx
mov temp, eax
mov eax, ebx
mov ebx, temp
mov edx, 0
jmp L1

L1:     ;divides until remainder is 0, then eax is GCD
```

This will switch the registers *no matter what* since regardless of the state of the carry flag, you run the code at `SWITCH`. Either you explicitly jump to there, or you fall through to there.

I suspect the `jmp L1` (which is superfluous at its current position, for reasons identical to the `jump if carry`) should be immediately after the `jc SWITCH` so that the whole thing either swaps or doesn't swap.

In other words, something like:

```
        jnc  L1       ; skip swap unless ebx > eax.
SWITCH: push eax      ; don't need temp at all, use stack.
        push ebx
        pop  eax
        pop  ebx
L1:
        mov  edx, 0   ; carry on.
```

Comment: So I put `jmp L1` into right after `jc SWITCH`. Now it says an error: integer overflow. What should I do...

Comment: No probs, @user4852500, but make sure you have a look at Michael's answer, that's probably the cause of your _immediate_ problem, running off into fairy land because you start running non-code due to lack of a return. If that is the case, you should accept his answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your `GCD` function is missing a return instruction:

```
DONE:      <-- There should be a RET after the DONE label  
gcd ENDP
```